# Can you determine whether a given T.Type is an array or a Dictionary?

Tags: swift, pattern-matching, codable

Writing some convenience methods for a JSON library I'm working on.  We have a function that takes a Codable.  Inside, I'm trying to determine if it's an array, an object (dictionary) or just a Codable value on its own.

Tried this, but all `Codable` variants return 'Codable'...

```swift
func check<T>(_:T.Type) {

    print("\(String(describing:T.self)) is ", terminator:"")

    switch T.self {

        case _ where T.self is Array<Codable>.Type:
            print("CodableArray")

        case _ where T.self is Dictionary<String, Codable>.Type:
            print("StringCodableDictionary")

        case _ where T.self is Codable.Type:
            print("Codable!")

        default:
            print("Not codable")
    }
}

class CodableThing : Codable {}
class NonCodableThing {}

check(CodableThing.self)
check([CodableThing].self)
check([String:CodableThing].self)
check(NonCodableThing.self)
check([NonCodableThing].self)
check([String:NonCodableThing].self)
```

Output...

```
CodableThing is Codable!
Array<CodableThing> is Codable!
Dictionary<String, CodableThing> is Codable!
NonCodableThing is Not codable
Array<NonCodableThing> is Not codable
Dictionary<String, NonCodableThing> is Not codable
```

So how do you detect the first two cases?

### Attempt #2

Restricting T to only take Codables, how can I simply check if it's a dictionary, an array or anything else? (Note this doesn't compile)

```
func check<T:Codable>(_:T.Type) {

    print("\(String(describing:T.self)) is ", terminator:"")

    switch T.self {

        case _ where T.self is Array.Type:
            print("CodableArray")

        case _ where T.self is Dictionary.Type:
            print("CodableDictionary")

        default:
            print("Codable")
    }
}

class CodableThing : Codable {}

check(CodableThing.self)
check([CodableThing].self)
check([String:CodableThing].self)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, not yet. Still looking... For now I just tried force-casting and it got me over my hump, but it technically doesn't solve this issue as I had to know the type internally to cast to.